# How to block ui while file download in asp.net C# without using cookie?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cookie-httponly

I have httponlycookie is true in web.config..so Server side cookie is not accessible in javascript to unblock ui.. is there any option to block ui without using cookie value

Block and unblock UI Code:

```
function blockUIForDownload() {
        $.blockUI();
       var start = new Date().getMinutes();
        var token = new Date().getTime(); //use the current timestamp as the token value            
        $("#<%= download_token_value_id.ClientID %>").val(token);
        $.blockUI();
        fileDownloadCheckTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
            var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
            if (cookieValue == token) {
                window.clearInterval(fileDownloadCheckTimer);
                $.removeCookie('fileDownloadToken'); //clears this cookie value
                $.unblockUI();
                var end = new Date().getMinutes();
                var time = end - start;
                //alert('Execution time: ' + time +' minutes');
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: where do you set the cookie value?

Comment: How do you initiate the download of your file? You could let jQuery handle the download using their ajax functions, block the UI on initiating the download and unblocking after you received the proper event from the ajax response using promises.